# Show dialog after webView on it loads Url

Tags: android, android-activity, webview

I have a Dialog Activity which have webview On it. i want to show dialog Only after webview completely loaded Url. is it possible to load url into webview before i display the dialog
I am trying following code.
this is my dialog activity

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button yes, no;
String url = "";
ImageView closeImageView;
static WebView newsWebViewDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_custom_dialog);

    try
    {
        if(null == getIntent().getStringExtra("url"))
        {
            url = "";
        }
        else
        {
            url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    closeImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_close);
    closeImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    newsWebViewDialog = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview_news_dialog);

    newsWebViewDialog.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    newsWebViewDialog.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    newsWebViewDialog.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    newsWebViewDialog.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    newsWebViewDialog.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url1) {
            if (url1.equals(url)) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url1));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return true;
        }


    });
    newsWebViewDialog.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
    });
    // newsWebViewDialog.loadUrl("http://www.back2cart.com/TestAdv.aspx");


    if(!url.equals(""))
    {
        newsWebViewDialog.loadUrl(url);
    }


}


@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v==closeImageView)
    {
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

and this is my layout_custom_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#00FFFFFF"
android:padding="5dp">
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview_news_dialog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="top|right"
        android:foregroundGravity="top|right"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/closebutton"
            android:background="#00000000"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Please Help me.

Comment: I am not sure about that. How about you show the dialog with a progress bar inside it and then show the webview when the page load is completed??

Comment: Try showing some kind of loader until webview is loaded.

Comment: i have used a loader but it takes a while before the url is loaded ,